# pandas: select neighboring rows of the selected row

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe contains several years' power load data. I want to select the **rows** having max value for **each year** and the +/- 5 days around that day.

Max of the year:

```
                 Max
2000-12-14    2009.347900
2001-02-22    1987.976074
```

Desired result:

```
                     Max
    2000-12-09    1949.279175
    2000-12-10    1901.194702
    2000-12-11    1827.509155
    2000-12-12    1579.835205
    2000-12-13    1780.223267
    2000-12-14    2009.347900
    2000-12-15    1845.129395
    2000-12-16    1795.377319
    2000-12-17    1741.817749
    2000-12-18    1747.508789
    2000-12-19    1800.817261
    2001-02-17    1703.080322
    2001-02-18    1792.888062
    2001-02-19    1777.731323
    2001-02-20    1700.863281
    2001-02-21    1624.189209
    2001-02-22    1987.976074
    2001-02-23    1898.503052
    2001-02-24    1809.863403
    2001-02-25    1660.542725
    2001-02-26    1792.182007
    2001-02-27    1770.865356
```

I am using `df.loc[df.groupby("Year")['Max'].idxmax()].Max` to get the max value of the year, but how can I select all neighboring rows?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(index = pd.date_range('01-01-2001','01-01-2002',freq='D'),
                  data = {'power':100*np.random.random(366)})
df.loc[df.power.idxmax() - np.timedelta64(5,'D'):df.power.idxmax() + np.timedelta64(5,'D')]
```

The `loc` method can take ranges as arguments.  Numpy timedelta is used to add and subtract days for the index.

EDIT: If you want to see 5 rows on either side of the max row, regardless of the time increment, reset the index of the dataframe.  The indices will now be integers, and you can get 5 rows on either side of the max in this way:

```
#reset index to list of integers
df = df.reset_index()
# index using integers
df.loc[df.power.idxmax() -5: df.power.idxmax()+5]
```

Comment: I tried that it's giving me a "TypeError: incompatible type for a datetime/timedelta operation [sub]" error

Comment: my mistake, I've edited my answer to include a minimal reproducible example

Comment: It solves part of the problem-it gives me the rows around the max, but as I have multiple years that I need to groupby first. it doesn't work. I am using df.loc[df.groupby("Year")['Max'].idxmax()-np.timedelta64(5,'D'):df.groupby("Year")['Max'].idxmax()+np.timedelta64(5,'D'),['Max']]

Comment: If you change the time frame in multiple year say 2001~2003, only the the max +/- 5 rows will be select. I would want to select max +/- 5 for each year. Any idea? Thank a lot.